# Kali or Ubuntu which is better for Machine Learning and Deep Learning

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kali-linux

I am beginner to learning ML and DL. I already have faced some problems in windows operating system that's why I want moved on Linux operating system but I am confused which one is better to learn ML and DL.

> Which problems I have faced in windows OS,

1. I can't install **tensorflow with keras**
2. After trying about 5 or more days when I failed to Install tensorflow and keras in **anaconda**
3. Although finally I successed to install tensorflow and kears to create the new environment in anaconda navigator but some of packages are installed step by step
4. Related to **point-3**: Again I had faced problems for specific packages
5. Then I decided to use **google colab**
6. In google colab, It takes more time to load the datasets and for every entre time I should load datasets, it takes more time

And for these above reason and some more , I further have decided to **Linux OS**. But I am confused about Ubuntu and Kali. I have listen that **Kali is better for Hacking and Ubuntu is for Development**.

> My laptop details are below,

- 8 GB RAM
- 1TB hard disk
- 7th Gen
- Core i5

Comment: Did u try with wsl2? You can even use Cuda from Linux distro on Windows now. Ive been using it from my windows computer.

Comment: No, I never used WSL2even I have no knowledge about WSL2.

Comment: U should look into it. Well it is like installing Ubuntu, Kali and stuffs. But Kali Linux is used for like hacking and stuffs. Dunno if it is suitable for ML. Maybe if u building a hacking tool based on ML maybe? I would go with Ubuntu. Tons of great docs + tutorials.

Comment: I am working Research based on Deep Learning. And for the purpose on researech , please recommend me as better options.

Comment: Deeeef Ubuntu mate. Try to install the Ubuntu Server in your windows system. `https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-on-wsl-2-is-generally-available` and you need to signup to the `Windows Insider Program`to use Nvidia's CUDA on WSL2 configuration. Which is what you need. However, I highly recommend you to use the native Ubuntu though.

Comment: @GI HYUN NAM,  Is there more tools and options to use friendly and works fast.???

Comment: You would want to use Ubuntu Server for your work. But, I dunno how good you are with it. You have to get used to the process like installing GPU to the system and installing CUDA. Ubuntu Server is super light and fastest to use. And, you would want to learn Docker. You can code on Windows or Mac, dockerize the code and run it on Ubuntu Server would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kali is a distro designed specifically for penetration testing. It's not very safe out of the box compare to other mainstream Linux distro. Kali also comes bundled with lots of tools that are not suitable for your use. It is recommended that you go with Ubuntu for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I have a question. have you experience on ubuntu to use ML and DL?

Comment: I'm managing a lot of Ubuntu server for other purposes than ml/dl. I've only done some sentiment analysis on Ubuntu. There are other great post on stack overflow catering to your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the informations ! I think I should used Ubuntu.

Comment: No problem. Glad that I helped. Maybe mark the question as resolved if there is no further questions.

Comment: Yea, sure ! It's enough to take the decision. Again thanks !